# How to Construct the Shared Access Signature URL using C#?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, azure, cloud, storage

Unable to generate signature (sig) part in the shared Access Signature while constructing URL to request list blob storage. Can anyone please provide a c# code to create sas?

Comment: I voted this one up because it makes perfect sense if you have a clue about blob storage and shared access signatures. Check it out, the two answers that were given were exactly what is needed. The question was tagged .net and Azure and mentions c#. This is very specific and the answers given were very spot on. Sorry Adam, but you were wrong to close this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.sharedaccesspolicy.aspx gives an example of how to create a shared access signature through the C# storage API.

Comment: Is there a PowerShell command to generate Shared Access Signature?

Comment: Link is broken...